# How to copy paste tables from many txt files into 1 excelsheet?

Tags: excel, vba

Steps I need to do:

1. Open all necessary files(which are from the same folder) in Excel
2. For the first file, copy from row 6 to bottom of table. For second and subsequent files, copy from row 7 to bottom of table (Note that each file has different number of table rows). (Reasoning is that rows 1-5 are irrelevant, row 6 has heading, and I only want the heading to appear once in the table)
3. Paste into main excelsheet, but without overlapping previous rows
4. Separate main excelsheet by commas (text to column)
5. Close all files other than main excelsheet

Tried to google the various steps, but each step's code does not work well with one another, resulting in numerous errors, so I gave up and tried to record macro, but I did not get a "for" loop.

Comment: I didn't understand well what do you want to do. So you have an excel file in a folder with some other text files. And then you want to read the first file from row 6 to the end and the others from row 7 to the end, and insert them into excel? In the same sheet or different sheets? What is the naming of the text files, what is the name of the first, do they have an order?

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested the code below

```
Sub Read_Texts()

'Variable Declaration
Dim sFilePath As String
Dim sFileName As String

'Specify File Path
sFilePath = "C:\Users\use\Desktop\New folder"

'Check for back slash
If Right(sFilePath, 1) <> "\" Then
    sFilePath = sFilePath & "\"
End If
    
sFileName = Dir(sFilePath & "*.txt")

Do While Len(sFileName) > 0
    If Right(sFileName, 3) = "txt" Then
        'Display file name in immediate window
        Dim hf As Integer: hf = FreeFile
        Dim lines() As String, i As Long
       
        Open sFileName For Input As #hf
            lines = Split(Input$(LOF(hf), #hf), vbNewLine)
        Close #hf
        
        If sFileName = "file1.txt" Then
            For i = 5 To UBound(lines)
                Debug.Print "File 1 Line"; i; "="; lines(i)
            Next
            Else
                For i = 6 To UBound(lines)
                    Debug.Print "File 1 Line"; i; "="; lines(i)
                Next
            End If
        End If
        'Set the fileName to the next available file
        sFileName = Dir
    Loop

End Sub
```

Change `C:\Users\use\Desktop\New folder` according to your folder path, and here you can do whatever with the returned lines `Debug.Print "File 1 Line"; i; "="; lines(i)`

Comment: Dim lines() As String, i As Long
lines = Split(Input$(LOF(hf), #hf), vbNewLine)

Hi, the code isn't working perfectly still, I made some minor changes. Do you mind explaining what these 2 lines are?